# Reemplazar valores de una lista en una matriz en Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Mi problema es el siguiente, quiero reemplazar una lista de preguntas en la primer fila de una matriz nula cuadrada dejando el primer cero, es decir, si la matriz es de m filas por n columnas, quisiera insertar la lista de preguntas a partir del valor [m,n] = [0,1]. En donde cada pregunta de la lista ocupe un lugar en esa fila de la matriz. De igual manera, me gustaría reemplazar esas mismas preguntas en la primer columna, dejando el primer valor como cero, a partir de [m,n] = [1,0]. El código que estoy utilizando por el momento es el siguiente:

```
numero_preguntas = (len(df1_number_rf.columns))
preguntas = np.array(df1_number_rf.columns.values)
matriz = np.zeros((numero_preguntas+1,numero_preguntas+1),)
```

Es decir, quisiera que esto:

```
[[0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]]
```

En base a una lista con preguntas:

```
preguntas = [pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3]
```

Se transforme en esto:

```
[[0,pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3]
 [pregunta1,0,0,0]
 [pregunta2,0,0,0]
 [pregunta3,0,0,0]]
```

Posteriormente tengo valores en una matriz que quiero insertar en valores específicos de la anterior. Por ejemplo:

```
[[pregunta1,0.8]
 [pregunta3,0.2]]
```

Deseo insertarlos en la columna de la pregunta 2 en las filas que se correspondan, de tal manera que quede así:

```
[[0,pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3]
 [pregunta1,0,0.8,0]
 [pregunta2,0,0,0]
 [pregunta3,0,0.2,0]]
```

Esto último lo necesito hacer porque estoy tratando de elaborar una matriz con los valores de las importancias obtenidas utilizando random forest de cada una de las preguntas. Es decir, la pregunta2 seria la variable a clasificar en un arbol de decisión y las preguntas 1 y 3 vendrían a ser los clasificadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No defines cual es el tipo de dato de `preguntas`, supongo que son cadenas. En un array de Numpy no se pueden mezclar tipos de datos sin más, para hacer esto necesitas usar un [array estructurado](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html) (`numpy.recarray`).

No obstante es mucho más simple usar Pandas para esto y dado que usas la etiqueta voy responder en este sentido:

```
import pandas as pd

numero_preguntas = 3
preguntas = ["pregunta1", "pregunta2", "pregunta3"]

matriz = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=preguntas, columns=preguntas)
```

Con esto obtenemos nuestro DataFrame con el índice y columnas (ambos con los valores de `columnas`) y lleno de ceros:

> ```
> >>> matriz
>
>            pregunta1  pregunta2  pregunta3
> pregunta1        0.0        0.0        0.0
> pregunta2        0.0        0.0        0.0
> pregunta3        0.0        0.0        0.0
> ```

Para actualizar una determinada columna puedes usar el método `update` de las series:

```
>>> values = [["pregunta1", 0.8], ["pregunta3", 0.2]]
>>> matriz["pregunta2"].update(pd.Series(dict(values)))

>>> matriz
           pregunta1  pregunta2  pregunta3
pregunta1        0.0        0.8        0.0
pregunta2        0.0        0.0        0.0
pregunta3        0.0        0.2        0.0
```

Dependiendo de donde vengan los datos para rellenar la matriz es posible que esto se pueda simplificar.